# OAuth with twitter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, tweetsharp

I download tweetsharp and twitterizer and I can not make it work. I try tweetsharp with the basic following sample

```
TwitterService Service = new TwitterService(consumerKeyTw, consumerSecretTW);
OAuthRequestToken requestToken = Service.GetRequestToken("http://localhost:1470/Twitterr/OAuth"); // <--  callback URL
```

I always get a false Token. I also try twitterizer, which came with a simple example. I copy and paste the keys. But I also never get back the token.

I try with tweetsharp deleting the url callback and it worked! But off course twitter didn't go to my callback url. 
On dev.twitter I setup for Registered Callback URL the above url. But I still don't get the token.

Any Idea? What I'am missing? Do you know any way to debug and test my code with a localhost?
Thanks!

Comment: Bear in mind that TweetSharp is no longer in development, if you need support and updates, prefer Twitterizer or some other .NET wrapper.

Comment: Since your code pertains specifically with Tweetsharp I've removed the Twitterizer tag. If you wish to submit a Twitterizer question, please do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered here: [The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. Twitter oAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267096/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-401-unauthorized-twitter-oauth)

Answer (score -1):

Most probably it's because of "localhost" not pointing to your webserver from twitters point of view.

Comment: on https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp there is an example with a localhost. How can I test my code from my local host?